# Downloading file from SFTP directly to HTTP response without using intermediate file

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, sftp, jsch

I am trying to download a file through SFTP using Java JSsch library. I am successful in downloading the file to a local directory. **But, all I need is to download the file directly to browser without giving any local destination path (like how file gets downloaded in Chrome). I am using Spring controller AngularJS Promise to catch the response. Below is my code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadAttachment", method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void downloadAttachment(
        @RequestParam(value = "fileName") String fileName,
        @RequestParam(value = "filePath") String filePath,
        @RequestParam(value = "fileId") String fileId,
        HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = null;
    if(!fileName.isEmpty() && !filePath.isEmpty() && !fileId.isEmpty()){
        String directory = filePath;
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch ssh = new JSch();
        Session session = ssh.getSession(sftpLogin, sftpAddress, 22);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setPassword(sftpPassword);
        session.connect();
        logger.info("Connection to server established");
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();

        ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        sftp.cd(directory);
        is = sftp.get(fileName);
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    is.close();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

I don't know the type of file to be downloaded. So, I used `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE`. This is giving me Exception which is given below.

> java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
>       java.io.PipedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       java.io.PipedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>       com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2909)
>       com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2935)
>       com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.access$500(ChannelSftp.java:36)
>       com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.read(ChannelSftp.java:1417)
>       com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.read(ChannelSftp.java:1364)
>       org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
>       org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are disconnecting channel and session before actually reading anything from input stream (stored in variable "is"). Please call following lines after IOUtils.copy() instead of before -

```
is.close();
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

You can also try directly calling

```
sftp.get(filename, response.getOutputSteam());
```

Have a look at documentation [here](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-)

Comment: This worked but the downloaded file doesn't have any content in it.

Comment: IOUtils.copy() return number of bytes copied. Can you log it and check if anything is copied at all?

Comment: It gave the number of bytes as 400535, which means something is copied.

Comment: I think then it is spring-mvc specific issue. Did you independently try downloading a file from local directory to web browser?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot close the SFTP session before you try to read the data.

This is the correct code:

```
is = sftp.get(fileName);
IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
is.close();
```